# How to fetch failing rows in dataframe.to_sql?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am executing below code -

```
try:    
     dataset.to_sql(name=schema.lower(), con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
except Exception as ex:    
     print("Data cannot be processed - ", ex)    
     exit(1)
```

This works really well if dataframe has valid rows.
But, if there's problem with 1 row, whole operation fails. Is there any way to process valid rows and capture failing rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any feasible solution, I used Pandas schema to validate data before pitching into database

[Here](https://tmiguelt.github.io/PandasSchema/) is the doc for Pandas schema. This solved my problem upto an extent.